# Misaligned UILabel

Tags: ios, optimization, uilabel, instruments

I have a view placed within a scrollview, and within this view there is a UILabel.
The UILabel is defined as following:
`label_ = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 20)];`
and without autoresizing mask.

When I turn on 'Color misaligned images' in Instruments in the 'Core Animation' tool, all the views are ok but the single UILabel is marked as misaligned.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score -4):

Alignment.  You are missing alignment.

EDIT:  Sorry, couldn't help myself.  I've never used that functionality in X-code, but my advice would be if the view looks ok in the app, then who cares what IB thinks...

Comment: Doing everything programatically - no IB.
Misalignment is a problem when elements are in a scroller moving around the screen + alot of other heavy work going on in the background.

Comment: A misaligned views needs to be interpolated with its surrounding pixels to determine what color values actually have to be sent to the screen buffer. This causes a GPU hit when rendering. You want to prevent misalignment whenever possible.